# SSMS unable to change Table View Type in Database diagram. SSMS 17

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-17

In SQL Server Management Studio 2017, When I am creating a new diagram & adding a new Table (or adding an existing table) to the diagram,
I am unable to change the Table View type to Custom.

Also, when I am modifying Table View "Custom" to include columns such as Default Value or Description, SSMS fails to update the table view type.

I have tried connecting instances of SQL Server 2008 R2 as well as SQL Server 2016 to the studio.

Is it a bug or is there a setting which I need to change ?

**Extra Info** : Downloaded it from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: Do you have an error code?

Comment: @Sourcery There is no code, I am changing things in management studio database diagrams.

Comment: Same here - it doesn't work

Comment: What is your version of SSMS 17.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it might be you hit a bug. i've tested it using SSMS 14.0.17213.0 (17.4) and the table view custom is working fine. please check again. You may need to update your SSMS as Microsoft updates SSMS every month to provide bug fixes and add new features.
HTH